# Hive QL runs fine in SQL Workbench but fails on Tableau

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, parseexception

```
    with loan_apps as 


(
SELECT 
m.LA_LOAN_ID Loan_ID,

m.aid BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,

m.app_create_dt APPLICATION_DATE,
CASE WHEN m.PROD_ID in (1006 ,1008) 
THEN 'TERM LOAN'
WHEN m.PROD_ID in(2000,2001,2002) 
THEN 'LOC'
ELSE m.PROD_ID 
END AS PRODUCT,
m.lc_loan_interest_rate as INTEREST_RATE,
m.lc_loan_apr as APR, 
m.con_fico as FICO,
CC.FICO_MIN,
CC.FICO_MAX,
CR.A_INCOME,
CR.A_DOB,
CR.CR_DTI,
LA.ORIG_FEE_FRACTION as ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
la.referer_id,
B.CITY_AREA as City_Area,
m.bus_zip as ZIP,
b.STATE as STATE,
b.dma as dma,
CASE WHEN m.loan_app_status =  0
THEN 'Internal'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 1
THEN 'Pending'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 2
THEN 'Failed Authentication'
WHEN m.loan_app_status  = 3
THEN 'Failed Credit Rules'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 4
THEN 'Passed Authentication'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 5
THEN 'Passed Credit Rules'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 6
THEN 'Submitted'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 7
THEN 'Duplicate'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 8
THEN 'Error'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 9
THEN 'Approved'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 10
THEN 'Rejected'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 11
THEN 'In Review'
WHEN m.loan_app_status = 12
THEN 'Offer Expired'
ELSE 'Other'
END AS APP_STATUS,      
m.l_pricing_grade as pricing_grade, 
m.m_risk_grade as risk_grade, --this is the column that risk uses
m.lc_loan_maturity_months as LOAN_TERM,
m.channel_group_2 as channel_group,
m.channel_group_1 as partner_name,
CASE WHEN m.loan_app_status IN (6,9,10,11) THEN LA.app_d ELSE NULL END LISTING_DATE,
m.l_desired_amount as APPLICATION_AMOUNT,  
CASE WHEN LA.LIST_D IS NOT NULL OR m.loan_app_status IN (6,9,10,11) THEN LA.APP_AMNT ELSE NULL END  LISTING_AMOUNT, 
L.APP_AMNT REDUCED_LISTING_AMOUNT,     
m.loan_purpose as purpose,
case when m.loan_registered = 1 then 1 else 0 end as REGISTERED, --flag that shows 0/1 for loan registered
CASE WHEN m.FI_PROVIDED = 1 AND m.RESPONSE NOT IN ('MOREINFO_NEEDED','TECHNICAL_ERROR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COMPLETED_APPS,
case when m.LOAN_OFFERED = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS LOANS_OFFERED,
case when m.LOAN_LISTED = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS LOANS_LISTED,
case when m.all_core_docs_received = 1 then 1 else 0 end as all_core_docs_received_flag,
case when m.FRONTEND_DECLINE = 1 then 1 else 0 end as frontend_decline_flag,
case when m.backend_decline = 1 then 1 else 0 end as backend_decline_flag,
case when m.LOAN_ISSUED = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS LOANS_ISSUED,
case when m.issued_loan_strt_dt is not null then m.issued_loan_strt_dt else null end as ISSUED_DATE, 
CASE WHEN m.issued_loan_strt_dt IS NOT NULL THEN m.l_funded_amnt ELSE NULL END ISSUED_AMOUNT, 
CASE WHEN m.loan_status = 1
THEN 'In-Funding'    
WHEN m.loan_status = 4
THEN 'Issued'    
WHEN m.loan_status = 6
THEN 'Paid Off'
WHEN m.loan_status = 10
THEN 'Current'
WHEN m.loan_status = 11
THEN 'In Grace Period'
WHEN m.loan_status = 12
THEN 'Late 16-30 Days'
WHEN m.loan_status = 13
THEN 'Late 31+ Days'
WHEN m.loan_status = 14
THEN 'Default'
WHEN m.loan_status = 15
THEN 'Charged Off'
WHEN m.loan_status = 2
THEN 'Expired'
WHEN m.loan_status = 3
THEN 'Declined'
ELSE 'Not Issued'
END AS LOAN_STATUS,
CASE WHEN B.CITY_AREA IN ('HOUSTON','DENVER','MIAMI-FT. LAUDERDALE')
THEN 'TEST'
WHEN B.CITY_AREA IN ('NEW YORK','LOS ANGELES','SAN FRANCISCO-OAK-SAN JOSE','DALLAS-FT. WORTH','SAN DIEGO')
THEN 'CONTROL'
ELSE
'OTHER'
END AS TEST_OR_CONTROL,
case when m.loan_registered=1 and m.pi_provided=0 then 'registered'
when m.pi_provided=1 and m.fi_provided=0 then 'pi_provided'
when m.fi_provided=1 and (case when m.PB_FLAG in ('PB DECLINE','PB APPROVED') then 1 else 0 end)=0 then 'fi_provided'
when (case when m.PB_FLAG in ('PB DECLINE','PB APPROVED') then 1 else 0 end)=1 and m.loan_offered=0 then 'app_completed'
when m.loan_offered=1 and (CASE WHEN la.sel_offer_item_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0 then 'offered'
when (CASE WHEN la.sel_offer_item_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1 and (CASE WHEN bi.business_tax_id_enc IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0 then 'offer selected'
when (CASE WHEN bi.business_tax_id_enc IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1 and m.loan_listed=0 then 'checked out'
when m.loan_listed=1 and (m.all_core_docs_received=0 and m.loan_issued=0) then 'listed'
when m.all_core_docs_received=1 and m.loan_issued=0 then 'docs uploaded'
when m.loan_issued=1  then 'issued or approved'
else null
end as funnel_action,
m.ver_b_revenue as revenue_last_yr,
m.u_inpt_net_profit as profit_last_yr,
m.num_of_employees_group_1 as head_count,
m.m_legal_structure as legal_structure,
m.years_in_business as years_in_business,
MKTC.name as campaign_name,
MKTC.id as campaign_id
FROM 
MARKETING.SB_LOANS_DATA_W_PERF_GRP m 
left join TLC.LC_LOAN_APP LA  ON M.la_loan_id=la.loan_id
left join TLC.LC_actor a on a.id=la.aid
LEFT JOIN marketing_temp.tv_ad_control_zipcode b ON m.bus_zip = b.zip_code
left jOIN TLC.LC_business_info bi ON bi.id = la.business_info_id 
left join TLC.LC_LOAN L on l.id=la.LOAN_ID
left join TLC.LC_CREDIT_CLASS CC on cc.id=la.CREDIT_CLASS_ID
left join TLC.LC_CREDIT CR on cr.id=la.CR_ID
left join TLC.LC_MKT_CAMPAIGN MKTC ON la.REFERER_ID = MKTC.OLD_CAMPAIGN_ID 
)

select 
Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'REGISTERED' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,
TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,

profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where REGISTERED = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'COMPLETED_APPS' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where COMPLETED_APPS = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'LOANS_OFFERED' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where LOANS_OFFERED = 1


union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'LOANS_LISTED' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
LISTING_DATE,
LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where LOANS_LISTED = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'all_core_docs_received' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where all_core_docs_received_flag = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'frontend_decline' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where frontend_decline_flag = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'backend_decline_flag' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
null as ISSUED_DATE,
null as ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where backend_decline_flag = 1

union all

select Loan_ID,
BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
purpose,
'LOANS_ISSUED' as action,
APPLICATION_DATE,
PRODUCT,
INTEREST_RATE,
APR,
risk_grade,
LOAN_TERM,
APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
partner_name,
channel_group,
STATE,
ZIP,
ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
null as LISTING_DATE,
null as LISTING_AMOUNT,
ISSUED_DATE,
ISSUED_AMOUNT,
APP_STATUS,
dma,
City_Area,

TEST_OR_CONTROL,
revenue_last_yr,
profit_last_yr,
head_count,
legal_structure,
years_in_business,
campaign_name,
campaign_id
from loan_apps
where LOANS_ISSUED = 1
```

This is the error message that I get while trying to execute the code in Tableau : [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 143:2 Failed to recognize predicate 'select'. Failed rule: 'queryStatementExpression' in subquery source'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau wraps your entire query in a sub query and Hive doesn't support using WITH.. within a sub query that is the reason why this query was failing when written as custom SQL within Tableau. The solution is to create a view and then refer the view in the custom SQL within Tableau.

```
    create view marketing_temp.apps
AS
SELECT m.LA_LOAN_ID ID,
         m.aid BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
         m.app_create_dt APPLICATION_DATE,
         CASE
           WHEN m.PROD_ID IN (1006,1008) THEN 'TERM LOAN'
           WHEN m.PROD_ID IN (2000,2001,2002) THEN 'LOC'
           ELSE m.PROD_ID
         END AS PRODUCT,
         m.lc_loan_interest_rate AS INTEREST_RATE,
         m.lc_loan_apr AS APR,
         m.con_fico AS FICO,
         CC.FICO_MIN,
         CC.FICO_MAX,
         CR.A_INCOME,
         CR.A_DOB,
         CR.CR_DTI,
         LA.ORIG_FEE_FRACTION AS ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
         la.referer_id,
         B.CITY_AREA AS City_Area,
         m.bus_zip AS ZIP,
         b.STATE AS STATE,
         b.dma AS dma,
         CASE
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 0 THEN 'Internal'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 1 THEN 'Pending'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 2 THEN 'Failed Authentication'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 3 THEN 'Failed Credit Rules'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 4 THEN 'Passed Authentication'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 5 THEN 'Passed Credit Rules'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 6 THEN 'Submitted'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 7 THEN 'Duplicate'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 8 THEN 'Error'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 9 THEN 'Approved'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 10 THEN 'Rejected'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 11 THEN 'In Review'
           WHEN m.loan_app_status = 12 THEN 'Offer Expired'
           ELSE 'Other'
         END AS APP_STATUS,
         m.l_pricing_grade AS pricing_grade,
         m.m_risk_grade AS risk_grade,

  --this is the column that risk uses
  m.lc_loan_maturity_months AS LOAN_TERM,
         m.channel_group_2 AS channel_group,
         m.channel_group_1 AS partner_name,
         CASE
           WHEN m.loan_app_status IN (6,9,10,11) THEN LA.app_d
           ELSE NULL
         END LISTING_DATE,
         m.l_desired_amount AS APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
         CASE
           WHEN LA.LIST_D IS NOT NULL OR m.loan_app_status IN (6,9,10,11) THEN LA.APP_AMNT
           ELSE NULL
         END LISTING_AMOUNT,
         L.APP_AMNT REDUCED_LISTING_AMOUNT,
         m.loan_purpose AS purpose,
         CASE
           WHEN m.loan_registered = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS REGISTERED,

  --flag that shows 0/1 for loan registered
  CASE
           WHEN m.FI_PROVIDED = 1 AND m.RESPONSE NOT IN ('MOREINFO_NEEDED','TECHNICAL_ERROR') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS COMPLETED_APPS,
         CASE
           WHEN m.LOAN_OFFERED = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS LOANS_OFFERED,
         CASE
           WHEN m.LOAN_LISTED = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS LOANS_LISTED,
         CASE
           WHEN m.all_core_docs_received = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS all_core_docs_received_flag,
         CASE
           WHEN m.FRONTEND_DECLINE = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS frontend_decline_flag,
         CASE
           WHEN m.backend_decline = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS backend_decline_flag,
         CASE
           WHEN m.LOAN_ISSUED = 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS LOANS_ISSUED,
         CASE
           WHEN m.issued_loan_strt_dt IS NOT NULL THEN m.issued_loan_strt_dt
           ELSE NULL
         END AS ISSUED_DATE,
         CASE
           WHEN m.issued_loan_strt_dt IS NOT NULL THEN m.l_funded_amnt
           ELSE NULL
         END ISSUED_AMOUNT,
         CASE
           WHEN m.loan_status = 1 THEN 'In-Funding'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 4 THEN 'Issued'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 6 THEN 'Paid Off'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 10 THEN 'Current'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 11 THEN 'In Grace Period'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 12 THEN 'Late 16-30 Days'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 13 THEN 'Late 31+ Days'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 14 THEN 'Default'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 15 THEN 'Charged Off'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 2 THEN 'Expired'
           WHEN m.loan_status = 3 THEN 'Declined'
           ELSE 'Not Issued'
         END AS LOAN_STATUS,
         CASE
           WHEN B.CITY_AREA IN ('HOUSTON','DENVER','MIAMI-FT. LAUDERDALE') THEN 'TEST'
           WHEN B.CITY_AREA IN ('NEW YORK','LOS ANGELES','SAN FRANCISCO-OAK-SAN JOSE','DALLAS-FT. WORTH','SAN DIEGO') THEN 'CONTROL'
           ELSE 'OTHER'
         END AS TEST_OR_CONTROL,
         CASE
           WHEN m.loan_registered = 1 AND m.pi_provided = 0 THEN 'registered'
           WHEN m.pi_provided = 1 AND m.fi_provided = 0 THEN 'pi_provided'
           WHEN m.fi_provided = 1 AND (CASE
           WHEN m.PB_FLAG IN ('PB DECLINE','PB APPROVED') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END) = 0 THEN 'fi_provided' WHEN (CASE WHEN m.PB_FLAG IN ('PB DECLINE','PB APPROVED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND m.loan_offered = 0 THEN 'app_completed' WHEN m.loan_offered = 1 AND (CASE WHEN la.sel_offer_item_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 'offered' WHEN (CASE WHEN la.sel_offer_item_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND (CASE WHEN bi.business_tax_id_enc IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN 'offer selected' WHEN (CASE WHEN bi.business_tax_id_enc IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND m.loan_listed = 0 THEN 'checked out' WHEN m.loan_listed = 1 AND (m.all_core_docs_received = 0 AND m.loan_issued = 0) THEN 'listed' WHEN m.all_core_docs_received = 1 AND m.loan_issued = 0 THEN 'docs uploaded' WHEN m.loan_issued = 1 THEN 'issued or approved' ELSE NULL END AS funnel_action,
         m.ver_b_revenue AS revenue_last_yr,
         m.u_inpt_net_profit AS profit_last_yr,
         m.num_of_employees_group_1 AS head_count,
         m.m_legal_structure AS legal_structure,
         m.years_in_business AS years_in_business,
         MKTC.name AS campaign_name,
         MKTC.id AS campaign_id
  FROM MARKETING.SB_LOANS_DATA_W_PERF_GRP m
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_LOAN_APP LA ON M.la_loan_id = la.loan_id
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_actor a ON a.id = la.aid
    LEFT JOIN marketing_temp.tv_ad_control_zipcode b ON m.bus_zip = b.zip_code
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_business_info bi ON bi.id = la.business_info_id
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_LOAN L ON l.id = la.LOAN_ID
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_CREDIT_CLASS CC ON cc.id = la.CREDIT_CLASS_ID
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_CREDIT CR ON cr.id = la.CR_ID
    LEFT JOIN TLC.LC_MKT_CAMPAIGN MKTC ON la.REFERER_ID = MKTC.OLD_CAMPAIGN_ID;

Drop view marketing_temp.apps_v2
create view marketing_temp.apps_v2
AS
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'REGISTERED' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE REGISTERED = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'COMPLETED_APPS' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE COMPLETED_APPS = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'LOANS_OFFERED' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE LOANS_OFFERED = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'LOANS_LISTED' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       LISTING_DATE,
       LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE LOANS_LISTED = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'all_core_docs_received' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE all_core_docs_received_flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'frontend_decline' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE frontend_decline_flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'backend_decline_flag' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       NULL AS ISSUED_DATE,
       NULL AS ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE backend_decline_flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       BORROWER_ACTOR_ID,
       purpose,
       'LOANS_ISSUED' AS action,
       APPLICATION_DATE,
       PRODUCT,
       INTEREST_RATE,
       APR,
       risk_grade,
       LOAN_TERM,
       APPLICATION_AMOUNT,
       partner_name,
       channel_group,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       ORIG_FEE_FRACTION,
       NULL AS LISTING_DATE,
       NULL AS LISTING_AMOUNT,
       ISSUED_DATE,
       ISSUED_AMOUNT,
       APP_STATUS,
       dma,
       City_Area,
       TEST_OR_CONTROL,
       revenue_last_yr,
       profit_last_yr,
       head_count,
       legal_structure,
       years_in_business,
       campaign_name,
       campaign_id
FROM marketing_temp.apps
WHERE LOANS_ISSUED = 1;
```

The code in Custom SQL part of Tableau will be :
    select * from marketing_temp.apps_v2

This resolved the issue at hand in Tableau.

Comment: Please ignore the Drop View part. I wrote it to ensure that the auto run of the code drops the view before re creating a pre existing view.